# Why is the Terminal.app 'open' command slower than opening a file via the Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

Sometimes when I use `open` in Terminal.app to open a file, the application spends ~45 seconds bouncing in the Dock, while the same file opens instantly when double-clicked from the finder.

Why does this happen?  Is there any way to make `open` consistently fast?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are these files that are quarantined after download? What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Nope, locally created files.  Right now 10.6.7, but I recall the problem happening at least as far back as 10.5.

Comment: FWIW, I think I actually found a solution to this problem years ago, perhaps relating to locale detection problems, but I seem to have lost the fix.

Comment: Locale as in the `LANG` environment variable? Also, have you checked the logs in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` for anything interesting?

Comment: Yes, or LC_something, but as I say, I don't remember the details.  Nothing in the logs.

Comment: What file types are affected, and what applications handle opening these file types?

Comment: Right now I'm seeing it for a .docx, but other .docx's open normally.  In fact, more playing with it has revealed that even *the same* docx doesn't have the problem if I make a copy of it.  No apparent differences with GetFileInfo.  Weird.

Comment: Ah, a breakthrough, it *is* quarantined, but doesn't bring up a warning, maybe docx's are considered safe. (I'd thought it was locally created because it was part of an SVN repo, but apparently not.) Removing that xattr makes it open nice and fast.  Put an answer about quarantine and xattr and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have previously experienced issues with quarantined files that were downloaded from the web and have the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute set.

To see if this is the case for your file, `ls -l@ filename.ext` in Terminal.

To remove the extended attribute, run `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine filename.ext`